# Bash - Parse a long string using awk to separate words

Tags: bash, shell, parsing, awk, mysql

I'm working on a bash script to perform some mysqldump backups. I'n not very good at scripting.

I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
TNAMES="database1.tableA database2.tableD databaseN.tableZ"
```

I need to parse TNAMES to separate the database part from the table part to execute the mysqldump

```
for TABLE in $TNAMES
do
  mysqldump $OPTIONS $USER $PASSWORD $DB $TABLENAME > "some_file.sql"
  (some more actions here)
done
```

so in the first loop iteration the command will be:

```
mysqldump $OPTIONS $USER $PASSWORD database1 tableA > "some_file.sql"
```

Next:

```
mysqldump $OPTIONS $USER $PASSWORD database2 tableD > "some_file.sql"
```

Next:

```
  mysqldump $OPTIONS $USER $PASSWORD databaseN tableZ > "some_file.sql"
```

And so on.

Is there any easy way to do this with awk?

Comment: Your question is not clear, what bothers you in the script you wrote?

Comment: You have already asked series of questions on this topic and haven't closed (accepted) any of the previous answers. Moreover this question is not clear at all. Why do you need awk if it is already working?

Comment: each >some_file.sql will overwrite the previous, are they different filenames or are you wanting >>some_file.sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "cut" for that:

```
for TABLE in $TNAMES
do
      DB=$(echo "$TABLE" | cut -d '.' -f 1)
      TABLENAME=$(echo "$TABLE" | cut -d '.' -f 2)
      mysqldump "$OPTIONS" "$USER" "$PASSWORD" "$DB" "$TABLENAME" > "some_file.sql"
done
```

Comment: as in the OP's example, this repeatedly overwrites some_file.sql without using it.

Comment: I'm well aware of that. But that's what the boy has asked for :)

Comment: This may work OK for your current input set but in general it has a few issues: 1) quote your variables, 2) avoid echo, 3) no need for cut, 4) backticks are deprecated. If this works for your current input set then just make sure you understand all of those caveats before applying this approach to any other problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Ed. I edited my answer: variables are now quoted and backticks have been replaced with $(). But why should I avoid echo?

Answer (score 2):

you don't need sed, awk or cut to perform simple prefix/suffix removal:

```
for spec in $TNAMES; do
  db=${spec%%.*}
  tb=${spec#*.}
  mysqldump ... $db $tb > $somewhere
done
```

Comment: +1 for using substring manipulation.  the $somewhere should probably be something like somewhere=$db-$tb.sql (otherwise only the last dump is available)

Comment: @technosaurus: sure, the snippet is decidedly not an SCCCE.

Comment: +1 for the right solution once you quote your variables (except `$TNAMES` of course).

Comment: @EdMorton i'll plead my ignorance.  can you show me a definition of *string* `$TNAMES` that would expand to words with embedded whitespace in a `for` loop?  it's not possible IMO.

Comment: White space isn't the most likely problem in this case, it's globbing characters. Try it if TNAMES contains, say,  a `*` or a `?` and you have matching file names in the directory you run it from. Actually, in this case it may not matter since you need to leave TNAMES unquote anyway, but quoting variables should be your default coding practice - leaving them unquoted is something you do when you want to produce some specific behavior, e.g. expanding `$TNAMES` in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Since your are initiating your variable in your bash you can use array:

```
Database[0]="database1"
Database[1]="database2"
...

Table[0]="tableA"
Table[1]="tableB"
...


# Loop over the table index
for i in $(seq 0 $((${#Database[@]}-1)))
do
   mysqldump $OPTIONS $USER $PASSWORD ${Database[$i]} ${Table[$i]} >> "some_file.sql"
done
```

I have take the liberty to happen to the file `>>` instead of creating a new file each time.

Comment: +1 for the array suggestion.  once you've declared dependency on bash(1), there's no reason to half-ass it.  otherwise you just limit you deployability in exchange for nothing in terms of expressiveness.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use something like

```
#!/bin/bash

TNAMES="database1.tableA database2.tableD databaseN.tableZ"
for TABLE in "$TNAMES"
do
    while IFS='.' read DB TABLENAME
    do 
      mysqldump "$OPTIONS" "$USER" "$PASSWORD" "$DB" "$TABLENAME" > "some_file.sql"
    done <<<"$TABLE";
done
```